# Can not change update-alternatives mvn

Tags: 14.04, command-line, update-alternatives

Ubuntu 14.04

After installing and changing the version of `mvn` via `update-alternatives, the configuration remains unchanged.

**Steps**

1. Install new version mvn

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mvn mvn /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn 100
   ```
2. Check alternatives

   ```
   $ sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
   There are 2 choices for the alternative mvn (providing /usr/bin/mvn).

     Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   * 0            /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn   100       auto mode
     1            /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn   100       manual mode
     2            /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn   10        manual mode

   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
   update-alternatives: using /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn to provide /usr/bin/mvn (mvn) in manual mode
   ```
3. Change alternative to new one

   ```
   $ sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
   There are 2 choices for the alternative mvn (providing /usr/bin/mvn).

     Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn   100       auto mode
     1            /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn   100       manual mode
   * 2            /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn   10        manual mode

   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
   ```
4. Check mvn version

   ```
   $ mvn --version
   Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
   Maven home: /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
   Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
   Java home: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre
   Default locale: ca_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
   OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-116-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
   ```

**`type` command output:**

```
$ type -a mvn
mvn is /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn
mvn is /usr/bin/mvn
```

Comment: Add the output of `type -a mvn`, please.

Comment: @muru I added it to the question

Comment: Your `PATH` probably has `/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin` in it. Remove it and try again.

Comment: It seems to be this, but I commented with # in .profile but it is still apearing in env and set, I'll try rebooting

Comment: you might have to login again.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!

Comment: You can post what you edited from your `.profile` as an answer.

Comment: This question solved my problem :D Thanks for the very detailed question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had modified the `~/.profile` `PATH` variable, so the only thing I had to do is to comment out the line and log in again.

**.profile**

```
...
#export PATH=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To include man page(s) and **mvnDebug** command within the alternative, just add *slave* options like this:

```
INSTALL_HOME="/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0"

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/mvn" "mvn" "${INSTALL_HOME}/bin/mvn" 100 \
  --slave "/usr/bin/mvnDebug" "mvnDebug" "${INSTALL_HOME}/bin/mvnDebug" \
  --slave "/usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz" "mvn.1.gz" "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvn.1.gz" \
  --slave "/usr/share/man/man1/mvnDebug.1.gz" "mvnDebug.1.gz" "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvnDebug.1.gz"
```

**Hint:** If your download did not include man pages, you can use [help2man](https://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/) to generate `mvn.1.gz` and then symlink `mvnDebug.1.gz` to it.

```
cd ${INSTALL_HOME}/man
ln -s mvn.1.gz mvnDebug.1.gz
```